# Accessing the content of a window opened with window.open

Tags: javascript, debugging

I know that I can access a window opened with window.open like so:

```
var myWindow = window.open('url','uniqueWindowId','argument=value,argument=value')
myWindow.document.getElementById('someId').display = "none";
myWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('someClass')[17].firstChild.style.backgroundColor = "red";
...
```

But I have, during debugging 3rd party code, the problem that I can't access the myWindow variable from the console (myWindow is scoped to the function only). Is there any way I can get the window, using its uniqueWindowId, from the parent window's javascript console?

Comment: I guess modifying the code to make the variable global is out of the question?

Comment: Since the js is running in your browser, I think you should be able to breakpoint on the line after `window.open` and do something like `window.globalMyWindow = myWindow` in the console so it remains accessible elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't standard function to get that but I can see a possible way:

```
function retrievePopupWindowHandle(windowName, callback){
  window.open('javascript:window.opener.handleRetrieved = window;', windowName);

  setTimeout(function(){
     var popupHandle = window.handleRetrieved;
     delete window.handleRetrieved;

     callback(popupHandle);
  }, 1);
}
```

But remember you're still under all security measures, like same protocol and origin policies.

It's not recommended but it would work.

A quick test to show it works (it will not work on jsfiddle due to security policies, create a file locally and open it in your browser):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="b">Create Window</button>
  <button id="b2">Retrieve Handle &amp; Test</button>  
<script>
var popupWindow;

function retrievePopupWindowHandle(windowName, callback){
  window.open('javascript:window.opener.handleRetrieved = window;', windowName);

  setTimeout(function(){
     var popupHandle = window.handleRetrieved;
     delete window.handleRetrieved;

     callback(popupHandle);
  }, 1);
}

document.getElementById('b').addEventListener('click', function(){
  popupWindow = window.open('about:blank', 'popupWindow');
});

document.getElementById('b2').addEventListener('click', function(){
  retrievePopupWindowHandle('popupWindow', function(popup){  
      if(popupWindow == popup)
        alert('Handles Match!');
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```